# Google Maps and Multiple Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So here is my code. The problem is the map shows, but no markers are placed on the map. 
    latlongARR is an array that looks like this

> [{"name":"McChord Field
>   DGC","lat":"47.128257","long":"-122.488847"},{"name":"Ambient
>   DGC","lat":"47.184732","long":"-122.509232"},{"name":"Riverside Disc
>   Golf Park","lat":"47.185683","long":"-122.212600"},{"name":"East
>   Tacoma DGC","lat":"47.227344","long":"-122.398491"},{"name":"White
>   River","lat":"47.278501","long":"-122.197390"}]

It seems everything should work?? any obvious mistakes ?

```
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom:10,
                    center: currentLocation,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dgmap'), mapOptions);
                var infowindow = null;

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'loading...'}); 

                var marker, i;

                for(i=0; i < latlongARR.length; i++){
                    var markers;
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlongARR[i][1], latlongARR[i][2]),
                        map:map
                        });
                        console.log(latlongARR[i][0]);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i){
                        return function(){
                            infowindow.setContent(latlongARR[i][0]);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                        })(marker,i));
                    };

                }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlongARR[i][1], latlongARR[i][2]),
```

`latlongARR[i]` is an object, you need to use the property name not the number index to get the value, the above code should be:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlongARR[i].lat, latlongARR[i].long),
```

or

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlongARR[i]['lat'], latlongARR[i]['long']),
```

Same problem of below:

```
infowindow.setContent(latlongARR[i][0]);
```

this should be `infowindow.setContent(latlongARR[i].name);`

Comment: The {map: map} in the MarkerOptions is equivalent to marker.setMap(map);

Answer (score 1):

You should use a debugger.  The first thing is this:

```
                   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlongARR[i][1], latlongARR[i][2]),
                    map:map
                    });
```

`latlongARR[i][1]` and `latlongARR[i][2]` are undefined, they should be `latlongARR[i].lat` and `latlongARR[i].long`.

Comment: thank you. I saw the undefined but did not realize it needed to be accessed using .lat .long. Totally worked. I am pretty new and learning these things is great. thanks for the help